# Suggestion to handle dead/broken links

Tags: feature-request, broken-link

It's aggravating to click on a link in an Answer and find out that it's dead.  When that happens can't SO automatically mark the link as broken?  Or give me a way to do so?  I don't mean for all links to be tested -- I'd just like to warn future visitors (maybe even me, later) that the link was broken so they can avoid it.  Make them a different color.

Comment: That's why we hate link only answers so much. An answer should NEVER just rely on a link :/.... (not fixing your issue at all, don't get me wrong)

Comment: What exactly stops you from editing post to do that (presumably in far more intelligent way than any "color differently" can provide)?

Comment: Try to suggest an edit to fix broken links with archive.org ones, or flag link-only answers as "not an answer".

Comment: It's too much of a burden for readers to edit other peoples posts.  I'm suggesting that SO automatically recognize that I've clicked on a dead link (see below) -- or at least let me come back and simply control-click on the link and mark it "dead". It has to be quick and easy or people won't bother.  It could be automatic if SO did its own check for a 404 or 503 response on, say, every 10th click on a particular link, and SO need only check links that people try to access. Anyway, I see now that many people are workings on this.  My automatic method might have been tried.